# Update_all query with joins in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, psql, rails-console

I have an trackers table and applications tables

application.rb
has_many :trackers

tracker.rb

belongs_to :application

What I trying to do is update the check_in_date in the trackers table to be query to begin_date in the applications tables only for those records which have check_in_date is equal to "2019-05-30".

I am trying to run the command below but I am getting an error.

```
Tracker.joins(:application).where("check_in_date = ?", "2019-05-30").update_all("tracker.check_in_date = application.begin_date")
```

error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "application")
```

Any idea where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try this:

**Note I have no idea if this will work so don't do it in production unless you can confirm**

```
  Tracker.where(check_in_date: "2019-05-30")
    .update_all("check_in_date = (#{  
         Application.select(:begin_date)
           .where('applications.id = trackers.application_id').to_sql})"
  )
```

The theory is that this should result in the following SQL

```
  UPDATE trackers 
  SET check_in_date = (
     SELECT 
        begin_date
     FROM 
        applications 
     WHERE 
        applications.id = trackers.application_id
  ) 
  WHERE 
    trackers.check_in_date = "2019-05-30"
```

Comment: **TypeError (can't quote ActiveRecord::Relation)**

Comment: @Navroop try now? I changed it to a SQL string

Answer (score 0):

There seems some typo

if `check_in_date` is `date` type then convert is `"2019-05-30"` in date

```
my_check_in_date = "2019-05-30".to_date
```

While using any `attribute` in the query model name should always be plural

```
Tracker.joins(:application)
          .where("trackers.check_in_date= ?", my_check_in_date)
          .update_all("trackers.check_in_date = applications.begin_date")
          .references(:application)
```

Comment: I tried it but I am still getting the error.. **ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "applications")**

Comment: @Navroop `references(:application)` just add in the query, hopefully, that should work.

Comment: I tried this as well. but it still the same error. If i remove the update_all portion to see if the query gets all the tracker record then it works but doesn't work with the update_all